# Swift - Delete CoreData row

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

I try to delete a row from coredata. I handle the row but I didnt delete. When I try **context.delete()** It requires **NSManagedObject** in (). How I convert this result to NSManagedObject ?

```
func deleteElement(postUid:String){

    let appDel:AppDelegate = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate)
    let context:NSManagedObjectContext = appDel.persistentContainer.viewContext

    let fetchRequest = NSFetchRequest<NSFetchRequestResult>(entityName: "Posts")
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "postUid == %@", postUid as CVarArg)
     fetchRequest.predicate = predicate

    do {

        let result = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)

        print("Result \(result)")



        try context.save()

    } catch {
        print("Error \(error)")
    }

}
```

// Result Print

```
Result [<Posts: 0x6080002901d0> (entity: Posts; id: 0xd000000000640000 <x-coredata://9A330E28/Posts/p25> ; data: {
item = "<relationship fault: 0x60c00022b900 'item'>";
lastMessageTime = "2018-05-23";
parentUid = nil;
postUid = "15e43d16";
title = Title;
userUid = ".."; })]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
let result = try context.fetch(request)
for object in result {
    let obj = object as! NSManagedObject
    context.delete(obj)
}

try context.save()
```

You basically need to fetch your objects and then delete them, one by one. Then you just save your context as usual.